# Custom Navigation Links

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation

I want to display navigation links on left side of Sharepoint Site. Basically these links will point to different website within the organisation. The links will be stored in SharePoint Links library. Is there any OOTB that will help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dataview webpart and display the links from any list or library.You can have  the webpart on master page.

Comment: Thanks amit. I used empty data view webpart and tweaked it to display the link.

Comment: Hi Amit, Do you know how to hide the dropdownlist when you hover cursor on a list item

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard or enterprise version of SharePoint I recommend you use a content query web part instead of a dataview webpart. They are a lot more modular in my opinion and can easily be added anywhere in the site collection without the need to update.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same scenario, where I need to create a custom left navigation for my site in SharePoint. I did some research and found multiple options, details are provided on my blog, let me know if you find this helpful:

1. [Configurable multi-level treeview left navigation in SharePoint](http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.in/2011/06/configurable-multi-level-treeview-left.html)
2. [Extend the Default Navigation Provider of SharePoint 2010](http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.in/2011/06/extend-default-navigation-provider-of.html)

Comment: hi nilesh, i used empty data view to configure it to use link library.

Comment: Yes Kannabiran, this approach is also good. but you will not get flexibility as you get in custom controls and custom code.